# Flask - inheritance - python's self issue

Tags: python, oop, flask, self

I have a little flask application, it is mostly written with methods (just one class).

Can someone explain me - example would be great - why I am receiving `1 missing argument` after adding `self` to method declaration?

Here is a code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
from flask import redirect, request, jsonify, url_for
from multiprocessing import Value
from flask_classful import FlaskView

#from settings import *
from utils.settings import *

import logging
import linecache
import os
import simplejson as json
import mysql.connector

counter = Value('i', 0)
app = Flask(__name__)


class FlaskCLS(FlaskView):
    app.debug = False
    app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("templates/static/")

    @app.route('/v1/api/cords', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
    def snd_post():
        res = make_response({'x': '55.333', 'y': '18.666'})
        return res

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
    def index():
        result = []
        data = request.data
        with counter.get_lock():
            counter.value += 1
            out = counter.value
            with open(str(out), 'a') as dumping:
                json.dump(data, dumping)

# ----------------------parser-section------------
        with open(str(out), 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for line in content:
                result.append(line.replace('\\', "").replace('"', "").
                              replace('{', "").replace('}', '').
                              replace(']', '').replace(',','\n').
                              replace('[',''))
        f = open(str(out), 'w')
        f.write('')
        f.close()

        with open(str(out), 'a') as appending:
            appending.write('')
            for line in result:
                appending.write(line)

# --------------------cords-grabbing-------------
        x = linecache.getline(str(out), 1)
        y = linecache.getline(str(out), 2)
        fx = open('x', 'w')
        fy = open('y', 'w')

        fx.write(x)
        fx.close()
        fy.write(y)
        fy.close()

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=db_host,
            user='root',
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
            password=password,
            buffered=buffered,
            database=database)
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute('select nazwa, x, y, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (x - 54.111), 2) + POW(69.1 *(18.222 - y)\
         * COS(x / 57.3), 2)) as distance from wet_dane having distance <125 order by distance;')
        mycursor.fetchall()
        mydb.commit()

# ---------------------empty-files----------------
        str_directory = '/var/www/html/'
        list_files = [x for x in os.listdir(str_directory) if x[0] != '.']
        for each_file in list_files:
            file_path = '%s/%s' % (str_directory, each_file)
            if os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:
                os.remove(file_path)
            else:
                pass
        return render_template('layouts/index.html')


flask = FlaskCLS()
# ---------------------runner-section-------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.disabled = True
    app.run(host, port, debug, ssl_context=context)
```

My point is - how properly add `self` to `index` and `snd_post` methods?
I want to pass - for example - `x` variable from `index` to `snd_post` in the same class.
Without `self` flask doesn't allow me to do such an operation.

Thanks.

Comment: I never saw class based views for Flask before. The project has not been updated since 2014. Probably die not use it except you have very special reasons.

Comment: PS please always add the import statements

Comment: @J.G.
imports added.

For classes I use `flask-classful`.
Maybe you have some solution for my problem?

Comment: Yes. Do not use it. It is unmaintained. Just use function based views

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Flask-Classful, but it looks that you are supposed to register the routes to the app this way:

```py
class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello"

QuotesView.register(app)
```

Instead of the `@app.route(...)` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've made a solution for this, now my main python file looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
from multiprocessing import Value
from utils.settings import *
from py_methods.post import Post
from py_methods.db_connect import Db_conn
from py_methods.empty_files_del import DeleteEmpty
from py_methods.files_operations import Files
import logging
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = False
app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("templates/static/")

@app.route('/v1/api/cords', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def snd_post():
    return Post.snd_post()

class Main():
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
    def index():
        Files.parsing()
        DeleteEmpty.del_empty()
        Db_conn.wet_db()
        return render_template('layouts/index.html')


# ---------------------runner-section-------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.disabled = True
    app.run(host, port, debug, ssl_context=context)
```

So it's just a runner - every method I wrote has own file and own class. This allow me to inheritance the variables. We can close this topic. Thansk for the answers.